# onbackpressed() from Activity to Specific Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a MainActivity class with 3 Fragments (each in their own class)
My third fragment (LoginFragment) will allow Login a user and then go to a new activity (new Intent) with some info for that user like the product.

If I press back on that Intent will go back to the LoginFragment.
I override the `@OnBackPressed` to start the MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

I need to know how to replace that Fragment with the LauncherFragment (Fragment 1) in MainActivity.

I have this solution but it takes 0.5 sec to 1-2 sec based on device

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

would be cool to go direct to Fragment 1 like to finish the third fragment thanks :)

Comment: you test this code in a real device?

Comment: @DavidHackro yes on a Nexus 6p and a emulator, the flags If I understand will recreate the fragments so thats the delay

Comment: If the device is taking 1-2 seconds to create a fragment or start an activity something is wrong.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman my Nexus6p is 0.5sec or faster but this is a good device what about other devices like other 80% that are slower

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue in this idea
**onBackPressed()** I call a new Intent but with **extras** 
In the MainActivity that has the 3 fragments onRestart() I check if it coming from this class ( has that extras ) than go to this fragment (click,replace,delete)

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.Intents.NAVIGATE_BACK, true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();

}
```

on the MainActivity I got this

```
@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        boolean navigate = intent.getBooleanExtra(Constants.Intents.NAVIGATE_BACK, false);
        if (navigate) {
            View homeView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.home);
            homeView.performClick();
            intent.removeExtra(Constants.Intents.NAVIGATE_BACK);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be as fast as possible, use one activity and fragments to vary the contents. Adding a fragment doesn't create a new window, whereas an activity does.

Also look at your application logic in fragment / activity startup (`onCreate()`, `onResume()`, etc). That's going to be the main factor.

Comment: I tried every think I see when OnRestart in Called on MainActivity and then goes to LoginFragment Im trying to get an idea how to go to LauncherFragment how to finish that LoginFragment

Comment: You don't "finish" a fragment. You can "add" a new fragment on top, you can "replace" it with another fragment, or you can "remove" that fragment.